# How can i pass an element of ArrayList to a function by reference

Tags: java

In the following code how do i pass proc to execute function as a reference so that after the function is executed its value is updated

```
public Process executeProcess(Process proc)
    {
        int remain=proc.getRemainingTime();
        if(remain-timeQuantum<=0)
        {
            proc.setRemainingTime(0);
            proc.setStatus(2);//2 represents terminated
            proc.setFinishTime(time);
            time=time+remain;
        }
        else {
            proc.setBurstTime(remain-timeQuantum);
            time=time+timeQuantum;
            proc.setStatus(1);// 1 represents waiting
            }
        return proc;
    }
    public ArrayList<Process> FCFS()
    {
        Process running;
        procList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Process::getArrivalTime));
        for(Process proc:procList) {
        running=executeProcess(proc);

        }
        return procList;
    }
```

Comment: tl;dr: yo cannot. Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't do that already?  `Process` is a class.  Any variable that refers to it is already a reference.  You are passing the value of a reference, which is for all intents and purposes the same as the original reference)

Comment: Don't call it functions, call it *methods*.